# "how to close keyboard with smooth slowly animation" in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-animation

[image]

Android animation keyboard open.

whenever i click done in the keyboard i want keyboard close slowly with animation.

Can i implement it on default keyboard to make this type of stuff or make custom keyboard for that.

please suggest me: i am just new android beginner.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> An app receives no notification of when a keyboard appears, and the android framework itself is responsible for either sliding the app or laying it out again. So customization isn't really possible. Which is probably a good thing- a keyboard is a separate app, and having written one I wouldn't want to even try to write the keyboard half of such an animation, we'd never get it to look right with all the various ways the app could do it.
>
> The closest you'll get is to specify the fields to pan rather than resize when the keyboard is opened.

Comment: mare defult j animation karavu se thay

Comment: i can used default animation in android